# Only Use The First Match For Every N Rows

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this.

```
Date  Number
1      1
2      0
3      1
4      0
5      0
6      1
7      0
8      0
9      1
```

I would like to create a new column that puts a 1 in the column if it is the first 1 of every 3 rows. Otherwise put a 0. For example, this is how I would like the new data.frame to look

```
Date  Number  New
1      1       1
2      0       0
3      1       0
4      0       0
5      0       0
6      1       1
7      0       0
8      0       0
9      1       1
```

Every three rows we find the first 1 and populate the column otherwise we place a 0. Thank you.

Hmm, at first glance I thought Akrun answer provided me the solution. However, it is not exactly what I am looking for. Here is what @akrun solution provides.

```
df1 = data.frame(Number = c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0))
head(df1,9)

Number
1      1
2      0
3      1
4      0
5      1
6      1
7      1
8      0
9      1
```

Attempt at solution:

```
df1 %>% 
group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 3, n()))) %>% 
mutate(New = +(Number == row_number()))



Number   grp   New
   <dbl> <int> <int>
1      1     1     1
2      0     1     0
3      1     1     0
4      0     2     0
5      1     2     0 #should be a 1
6      1     2     0
7      1     3     1
8      0     3     0
9      1     3     0
```

As you can see the code misses the one on row 5. I am looking for the first 1 in every chunk. Then everything else should be 0. 
Sorry if i was unclear akrn

Edit** Akrun new answer is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much

Comment: Are you looking for the first occurrence of 1?

Comment: yes. First occurrence of 1 in each chunk. The way you chunked it was correct.

Comment: Can you please check my update

Comment: as always, thank you for taking the time. That is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I did noticed that there was a discrepancy before, but then I thought that the expected output can have some typo.  thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option to create a grouping column with `gl` and then do a `==` with the `row_number` on the index of `match`ed 1.  Here, `match` will return only the index of the first match.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 3, n()))) %>% 
   mutate(New = +(row_number() == match(1, Number, nomatch = 0)))
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   grp [4]
#   Number   grp   New
#    <dbl> <int> <int>
# 1      1     1     1
# 2      0     1     0
# 3      1     1     0
# 4      0     2     0
# 5      1     2     1
# 6      1     2     0
# 7      1     3     1
# 8      0     3     0
# 9      1     3     0
#10      0     4     0
#11      0     4     0
#12      0     4     0
```

Comment: Thanks akrun! Ill accept answer after 5 minute mark. But could you explain what is happening inside mutate? Thank you very much

Comment: @JordanWrong thanks, I updated with some description

Comment: at first glance I thought it was solved. But it was not. I updated the original question

Comment: This appears to be a preferable answer based on the revised post.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the logic, perhaps you want to check if `Number == 1` and that the prior 2 values were both 0. If that is not correct please let me know.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(New = ifelse(Number == 1 & lag(Number, n = 1L, default = 0) == 0 & lag(Number, n = 2L, default = 0) == 0, 1, 0))
```

**Output**

```
  Date Number New
1    1      1   1
2    2      0   0
3    3      1   0
4    4      0   0
5    5      0   0
6    6      1   1
7    7      0   0
8    8      0   0
9    9      1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `replace` `Number` value to 0 except for the 1st occurrence of 1 in each 3 rows.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(gr = ceiling(row_number()/3)) %>%
  mutate(New = replace(Number, -which.max(Number), 0)) %>%
  #Or to be safe and specific use
  #mutate(New = replace(Number, -which(Number == 1)[1], 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-gr)

# A tibble: 9 x 3
#   Date Number   New
#  <int>  <int> <int>
#1     1      1     1
#2     2      0     0
#3     3      1     0
#4     4      0     0
#5     5      0     0
#6     6      1     1
#7     7      0     0
#8     8      0     0
#9     9      1     1
```